# Prove $x<y \land z>0 \Rightarrow x\cdot z < y \cdot z$ for all$x,y,z\in \mathbb{K}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, field-theory, axioms

is it possible to prove it like that:

$\begin{gather*}
x\cdot z < y\cdot z \quad | \cdot z^{-1} \\
x\cdot \underbrace{(z \cdot z^{-1})}_{\overset{}=1} \overset{}< y \cdot \underbrace{(z \cdot z^{-1})}_{\overset{}=1} \\
1\cdot x \overset{}< 1\cdot y \\
x \overset{}< y  \quad \Box
\end{gather*} $

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is $\mathbb{K}$? It looks nice as long as you have inverses. Also, you started with what you wanted to prove and ended at your conditional. Typically, we would do it the other way.

Comment: $\mathbb{K}$ is an ordered field.

Comment: How do you know that multiplying by $z^{-1}$ mantain your inequality sign? You are using the proposition to prove the proposition, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x<y$ then $0<y-x$. Since $0<z$. Then, by multiplicative axiom, you have $0<(y-x)(z)$. So, $0<yz-xz$. Hence $xz<yz$.